# Amazon Rekognition Compare Photos Access Denied Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, compare, amazon-rekognition

I want to compare two photos. When I connected to AWS I try to connect to `AmazonRekognitionClient`:

```
CompareFacesResult result = new 
AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider).compareFaces(request);
```

But have this error:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::475877890857:assumed-role/wsirstpp-20181028230251-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: rekognition:CompareFaces (Service: AmazonRekognition; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 7f665a07-db54-11e8-8773-2de830a9e39f)

Full code for getting information about photos:

```
ByteBuffer image1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageSource);
ByteBuffer image2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageTarget);

CompareFacesRequest request = new CompareFacesRequest()
    .withSourceImage(new Image().withBytes(image1))
    .withTargetImage(new Image().withBytes(image2))
    .withSimilarityThreshold(70 F);

CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    context,
    "us-east-2:My_pool_Id", // Identity pool ID
    Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
);

CompareFacesResult result = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider).compareFaces(request);

List < CompareFacesMatch > faceMatches = result.getFaceMatches();

for (CompareFacesMatch match: faceMatches) {
    Float similarity = match.getSimilarity();
    Log.d(TAG, "run: similarity:" + similarity.toString());
}
```

What is wrong? What I did wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was in Cognito rules. Firstly need to create a rule and then edit rule

Answer (score 0):

The part of your error message, "unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials" suggests you are making the request with an unathenticated Cognito user. Unauthenticated Cognito users can be assigned IAM roles with permission policies to do various tasks but you've got to specifically allow that with your setup.

Are you using Cloudformation to set up your roles and permissions? I use serverless framework but it's mostly the same as Cloudformation.

In my app, I don't let my Cognito Unauthorized users do much, but my Cognito Authorised users are permitted to invoke a lambda, and that lambda is authorised to perform various rekognition requests.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have resolved this. The cause was in Cognito rules. Firstly need to create a rule and then edit rule